# fildowns formulas EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to defying a formula first to be filled down later, but got an error application-defined or object-defined error, i am not doing anything wrong.
Thanks for help

```
Sub FillCells()
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Formula = "=POWER(A1;2)"
     Range("B1:B5").FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest you try using either US syntax (eg: comma separator instead of semicolon), or the `.FormulaLocal` property instead of `Formula`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested my comment.  VBA is US-centric with regard to the `.Formula` property (as well as in other areas).  So you can either use a comma in your formula; or use the `.FormulaLocal` property.

Either solution works here without raising the error message.